# Permissions UMASK for New Directories

Tags: linux, permissions, umask

I have a directory "dir1" who's owner is "owner1" and it has 775 permissions.

Another user in the same group as "owner1" is called "owner2"

Whenever a file is written to "dir1" by "owner2" I need the permissions to be 600, and if it writes a directory, I need it to be 700.

How can I do this?  Do I need a UMASK?

Answer (score 1):

If the "owner2" will have `umask 077` it will clear `group` and `other` permissions from the list for all files created while this is set.  The problem of course would be that "owner1" won't be able to read those files.

If there is a specific program that creates files in "dir1" then the shell from which this program has been started can have `umask 077` set for it.

**Example**

```
umask 077 ; ./start_creator_owner2
```

If this line is part of the start script then the everything created by `start_creator_owner2` will have `go` permissions of `0`.